# Why is the custom tkinter placeholder text for an entry box ignored?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ui

ui.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ui.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

root = ui.CTk()
root.geometry("500x350")

frame = ui.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

label = ui.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="Login System", font=("Roboto", 24))
label.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

username = tk.StringVar()
entry1 = ui.CTkEntry(master=frame, textvariable=username, placeholder_text="Username")
entry1.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

password = tk.StringVar()
entry2 = ui.CTkEntry(master=frame, textvariable=password, placeholder_text="Password", show="*")
entry2.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

def login():
    print(username.get())
    print(password.get())

button = ui.CTkButton(master=frame, text="Login", command=login)
button.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

checkbox = ui.CTkCheckBox(master=frame, text="Remember Me")
checkbox.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is my code. The problem is that the placeholder text doesn't show up when I pass a text variable argument.

```
entry1 = ui.CTkEntry(master=frame, placeholder_text="Username")
```

shows the placeholder but doesn't pass the textvariable

```
entry1 = ui.CTkEntry(master=frame, textvariable=username, placeholder_text="Username")
```

passes the textvariable but doesn't show the placeholder

I've seen similar questions but they don't work for the custom tkinter widget and they don't use the placeholder argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholder text is only activated when, the `placeholder` attribute is set, and the value of the `textvariable` attribute is `None` or `""`. Since in your example the value of `textvariable` is `StrinVar()`, the second condition fails and the placeholder is never shown.

However you don't really need both anyway.  You can simply delete the `textvariable` and the `username` and `password` `StringVar`s and just call `get()` on the `entry` widgets directly in order to get the values in the same manner.

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ui

ui.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ui.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

root = ui.CTk()
root.geometry("500x350")

frame = ui.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

label = ui.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="Login System", font=("Roboto", 24))
label.pack(pady=12, padx=10)


entry1 = ui.CTkEntry(master=frame, placeholder_text="Username")
entry1.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

entry2 = ui.CTkEntry(master=frame, placeholder_text="Password", show="*")
entry2.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

def login():
    print(entry1.get())
    print(entry2.get()) # call get() on the entry widgets

button = ui.CTkButton(master=frame, text="Login", command=login)
button.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

checkbox = ui.CTkCheckBox(master=frame, text="Remember Me")
checkbox.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `customtkinter.StringVar()`.

Snippet:

```
username = customtkinter.StringVar(value="test")
entry_1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app,
                                 placeholder_text="placeholder",
                                 textvariable=username)
entry_1.pack(pady=20)
```

Btw, you will do same as password too.

Answer (score 0):

f1 = Frame(f7,background=secondColor,relief='sunken',border=5)
f1.pack(side='right',ipady=1800,pady=0)

```
    def en_Title():
        global entry_and_entryTitle
        global En1
        def entry_and_entryTitle(master,textvar, placeholder):
            En1 = ctk.CTkEntry(master=master, textvariable=textvar, border_width=1, font=(mainFont, 13), border_color=blackColor, justify='center', text_color=whiteCol)
            En1.insert(0, placeholder)
            En1.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: on_entry_focus_in(En1, placeholder))
            En1.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: on_entry_focus_out(En1, placeholder))
            En1.pack(pady=3)

            def on_entry_focus_in(entry, placeholder):
                if entry.get() == placeholder:
                    entry.delete(0, 'end')

            def on_entry_focus_out(entry, placeholder):
                if not entry.get():
                    entry.insert(0, placeholder)

        entry_and_entryTitle(master=f1,textvar=NAME_var,placeholder='NAME')
        entry_and_entryTitle(master=f1,textvar=WORKERS_PHONE_var,placeholder='PHONE')
        entry_and_entryTitle(master=f1,textvar=WORKERS_ID_var,placeholder='ID')
        entry_and_entryTitle(master=f1,textvar=WORKERS_DATE_var,placeholder='DATE')
        entry_and_entryTitle(master=f1,textvar=COMPANY_NAME_var,placeholder='COMPANY_NAME')
    en_Title()
```